# Functional Analysis: countable Product of Compact Subsets of Metric Spaces is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, product-space

I'm revising for Functional Analysis exam and I'm trying to solve this problem. The part a) is clear for me but I have problem with b) and c) and hope someone can give me a hint how to start/solve it.
I think that in part c) the theorem of Tychonoff plays a role. But here we have compact SUBSET of $X_n$, so I'm not sure if it's even allowed or how I must argue that I can use the theorem.
For b) I don't have an idea at all. If someone could give me hint how to start that would be great.

The problem:
Let $(X_n,d_n)$,$n \in \mathbb N$, be a family of metric spaces and X the product space $X=\prod_n X_n$. Define $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ for $x=(x_n)_{n\in N}, y=(y_n)_{n\in N} \in X$ as follows:
$\sum_{n \in I} \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{d_n(x_n,y_n)}{1+d_n(x_n,y_n)}$.

Prove:

a) d is a metric on X. --> I have already done this.

b) Any open neighborhood $U \subset X$ of an arbitrary point $x \in X$ contains a neighborhood of thr form $\prod_{1\le n\le N} U_n(x_n) \times \prod_{n \gt N} X_n$, where $N \in \mathbb N$ and for each $1\le n\le N,U_n(x_n)$ denotes an open neighborhood of $x_n in X_n$.

c) If for any $n \in \mathbb N, K_n \subset X_n$ is compact, then $\prod_{n \in N} K_n$ is a compact subset of X.

Answer (score 1):

As you are dealing with metric spaces you may instead concentrate on sequential compactness. For this it suffices to take any sequence $(\xi_k)_{k\geq 1}$ in the product $K=\prod_n K_n$ and use the socalled 'diagonal' trick to extract a subsequence that converges in $K$.

Comment: Okay, I will try it. But is it sufficient to argue with sequential compactness? I know sequentially compact metric space is compact.  But is it also true the other way around?

Comment: Yes, for metric spaces there is equivalence (see e.g. S Lang, Real and functional analysis, thm 3.8, but it should appear in most textbooks). The diagonal trick is the same as in Ascoli (if you know this?) and it is pretty much equivalent to your statement.

Comment: Yea, I think you mean the Cantor's Diagonal Argument, right? I think I've had it in Analysis. Thanks for the hint. Do you might also have a hint for part b?

Comment: For b) your nghd must contain an $r>0$ ball around $x$. Then you may  pick $n_0$ so that $2^{-n_0} < r/4$ and pick ngbhs in the first $n_0$ coordinates which have diameters smaller than $r/2$ in total. Then the ball of radius $r$ contains their product times anything in the remaining coordinates. Don't know if that is sufficiently clear?

Comment: I tried to draw it understand your intention. But I got stuck. Why picking smaller r/4 resp. r/2 arbitrarily? It just had to be smaller than the ball radius? And how does one choose n_0? Could you explain me why one could do it like this? I mean the idea behind this proof.

Comment: Suppose $B(x,r)\subset U$ for some $r>0$. As $2^{-n}$ goes to zero there is $N$ large enough so that $2^{-N}<r/3$. In the first $N$ coordinates you now choose neighborhoods (e.g. balls) $U_1,...,U_N$ of $x_1,...,n_N$ so that the sum of diameters is smaller than $r/3$. For the coordinates $n>N$ you pick simply $X_n$ and note that for the metric $d$ their diameter does not contribute more than $\sum_{n>N} 2^{-n} = 2^{-N}<r/3$ so summing up we see that this gives a ngbhd of the wanted type containing $x$ and of diameter not greater than $2r/3$ thus sitting inside $B(x,r)\subset U$.